# Is it possible to create a route that points to an absolute external URL?

Tags: php, symfony, routes, yaml

Google, as well as Symfony Docs and Cookbook haven't helped.

Let's say we have a website called `http://www.example.com` that is running on Symfony2 and we are using an external FAQ and Support Service (for whatever reason) located at `http://example.externalservice.com`.

We now thought it would be a suitable solution to create a route that points to the external FAQ service which would result in something like that:

```
# ../config/routing.yml
[...]

info.faq:
    url: http://example.externalservice.com     # Surely isn't working

[...]
```

This, because there could be a need to replace the support service with a home-brewed solution located within the application in the medium term. This route is used on various pages, so hardcoding or replacing them all when the support service changes is not an option.

So, my questions are:

- Is this the right approach or should we be using a TWIG extension and a parmeter located either in `parameters.yml` or `config.yml`?
- If it is the right approach, is it possible to create such a route without modifying the routing component itself?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well you could always create a regular route pointing on a regular action in a controller, and the action would just redirect to the external site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create the route in symfony 2 which maps to external URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878640/how-to-create-the-route-in-symfony-2-which-maps-to-external-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your parameters.yml add

```
external_url: http://example.externalservice.com
```

then in your controller :

```
$url = $this->container->getParameter('external_url');
return $this->redirect($url);
```

Comment: We did this one, because the call to the external web service needed some business logic that had to be done in a controller: We needed to pre-fill some form fields in the external contact form with data from the current user via GET parameters (such as eMail address etc.), so this was the way to go. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

From the Symfony2 documentation:

```
root:
    path:  /
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: http://www.google.fr
        permanent: true
```

For more informations about redirection, read the documentation below:

[How to configure a redirect to another route without a custom controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/redirect_in_config.html)