# How to create the route in symfony 2 which maps to external URL?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Referring to this,

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html

we can map url pattern to controller and action

app/config/routing.yml

```
blog_show:
    path:      /blog/{slug}
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:show }
```

I want to map the path to external url.

app/config/routing.yml

```
blog_show:
    path:      /blog/{slug}
    defaults:  "www.example.com/blog"
```

The requirement is, my current website is in kohana, I am porting it gradually to symfony 2. For my symfony2 app kohana URL are like external urls, I want to configure these urls in routing and use them in standard way,

e.g. in Twig,

```
<a href="{{ path('blog_show'}}">
  Read this blog post.
</a>
```

So later on when I port my pages to Symfony, I will have to change only routing file so that I could use same blog_show key to refer to url and  I wont'  have to change all the files where I have used urls.

Comment: if you need more than stock `Redirect:urlRedirect` provides (as described by https://stackoverflow.com/a/22861229/719662), simply write your own controller handling the redirects with a way incorporating the custom functionality you need (e.g. slugging)

Answer (score 9):

You can do this by using one of the Symfony framework controllers although I'm not sure how this would work with parameters:

```
blog_show:
    path: /blog/{slug}
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: "http://example.com/blog"
        permanent: true
```

Note that `path: /blog/{slug}` grabs the slug directly, but `path: "http://example.com/blog/{slug}"` doesn't work.

*Source*: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/redirect_in_config.html

Comment: A very helpful answer - though I've edited the 2nd part since it doesn't work as described (`RedirectController.php` shows no provision to handle slugs by itself). BTW: this method also works for local path redirects to directories not handled by Symfony directly (e.g. `path: "/some-local-path-to-a-directory"`).

Answer (score 1):

As of Symfony 2.2 this is possible by adding the host constraint to the routes:

routing.yml

```
user_homepage:
  path: /path/to/whatever
  host: "sub.domain.ext"
  defaults: 
    _controller: forExampleAnyNamespaceBundle:Controller:action
```

There's an official blog post on this issue: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-2-url-host-support-in-the-routing

Comment: this ain't what OP was asking about IMO

Answer (score -2):

The router feature of Symfony doesn't work that way...

I suggest you create a Twig extension for this. Read more about this here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

You could create a function that works very similar to the regular url() function, so you can migrate as easily as possible.

```
{{ legacyUrl('blog_post', {slug: 'my-blog-post'}) }}
```

After you migrated the blog to Symfony, all you need to do is create a route called "blog_post" and change "legacyUrl" to "url".

Comment: I wanted to avoid making changes to all twig template files once I port my all external urls in to symfony. I would just want to change routes.

Comment: You could give the function a more generic name, ie. getUrl(). After migration you can adapt that function so it works the same way as the default url() function.

Comment: actually, Symfony router *does* work that way - you can redirect either in your own controller, or use a stock one (like https://stackoverflow.com/a/22861229/719662 describes)

Answer (score -2):

Seems there is no native Symfony way to handle this problem.