# Symfony2 routing.yml to external url

Tags: php, symfony

My question is: How can I generate external url from routing.yml?

I want something similar to:

```
documentation_product1:
    pattern:  /my/documentation/product1.php
    default:  http://www.myothersite.com/product1
```

Is it possible or something similar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create the route in symfony 2 which maps to external URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878640/how-to-create-the-route-in-symfony-2-which-maps-to-external-url)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Symfony routes the requested url to a pair of controller and action to execute. It does only internal redirects.

For a redirect to an external URL you need .htaccess and mod_rewrite (if you use apache).

Comment: Or other webserver-related directives, depending on web server, if apache is not used

Comment: This is not true (anymore). It's possible to redirect to an external URL just via routing config, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17469952/283097

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to redirect within a controller to an external site

```
documentation_product1:
pattern:  /my/documentation/product1.php
defaults:  { _controller: AcmeBundle:Product:show }

// in controller
$this->redirect('http://www.myothersite.com/product1');
```

But it is not a good practise.

It is better to use the RedirectController from the FrameworkBundle.(mantioned by Paulpro)

Doku:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/redirect_in_config.html

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/RedirectController.php

Comment: If the whole purpose is to do a redirect, you can just use the existing RedirectController in the FrameworkBundle.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know the controller :)

Comment: This seems like the better of the two answers in the sense that the accepted answer doesn't seem to answer the question properly.